# Prompt the user to unmount a USB device

Tags: java, android

I am writing an Android App for which the user is required to connect an external storage through the USB-C port of a tablet.
Once operations on the external storage are complete, I would like the user to unmount the USB device correctly, which means he should either:

1. tap the "unmount" button in the "USB storage added" notification that automatically appears as soon as the device is connected.
2. Open the Storage settings page, tap on the external USB device and press "unmount".

Ideally, this process would be quick and as automated as possible. My understanding from reading other questions is that I cannot re-implement in my app the functionality of the button in option 1, because apps are not allowed to mount and unmount storage units.
What I can do is open the settings page [ACTION_MEMORY_CARD_SETTINGS](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Settings#ACTION_MEMORY_CARD_SETTINGS), except on Android API level 33+ this specific action does not open the Storage settings anymore, but the *Internal Storage* settings. So I have two questions:

- Is there an easier way of unmounting the storage for the user?
- In case there is not, is there an equivalent action to ACTION_MEMORY_CARD_SETTINGS for API level 33+, that opens the specific memory setting page where a user can unmount an *external* USB device?